# Are sounds expanded in memory when played with Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, memory, web-audio-api, audio-player

I'm beginner with Web Audio and wanted to know, if compressed (AAC, MP3, OGG) sound effects or especially music tracks are expanded in memory into megabytes, like textures in WebGL?

For example if I have an audio file with some music and file size is around ~3 MB (in any of the formats: MP3, OGG, AAC), will the file be expanded (decompressed) into 70 MB for playback like the original PCM format would take?

Also, is it possible to estimate how much memory an audio file uses when using Web Audio, with regular playback, without additional sound effects of the Web Audio's more advanced nodes.

Comment: they are expanded in chunks into a limited playback buffer. the size of it depends on the browser, bitrate, channel count, etc. if memory is a true concern for you here you should not use a browser in the first place.

Comment: I just wanted to know how it works and what limits there might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, to use a compressed audio file you must load the compressed audio file into memory and then use `decodeAudioData` to convert the compressed file to an `AudioBuffer`, consisting of float arrays internally---essentially PCM. (Firefox, however, has an optimization where, in many cases, it can use arrays of 16-bit integers instead of floats.)

If you use the number of channels and the duration of an `AudioBuffer`, you can get a pretty good estimate of the memory used.

If this is not suitable for you uses, the only alternative is to use a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` and friends to stream the compressed file to the browser.  You lose sample-accurate control of the source, however.